# get data using a lower or upper case using mysql like query?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to search for data from the database using MySQL `like` query

here is my query:

```
global $wpdb;

if($_GET['search']){
    $search = $_GET['search'];
}
else{
    $search = $_GET['searchtop'];
}

$search_details = $wpdb->get_results(
   $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM 
               tbl_brand,
               tbl_generic,
               tbl_therapeutic_area,
               tbl_drug 
         WHERE 
               tbl_brand.generic_id = tbl_generic.generic_id 
         AND 
               tbl_brand.therapeutic_area_id = 
               tbl_therapeutic_area.therapeutic_area_id 
         AND 
               tbl_brand.brand_id = tbl_drug.brand_id 
         AND 
               tbl_brand.brand_name LIKE '%$search%'",""
        ),ARRAY_A
    );
```

My data is like `DUET` {upper case letter} in database I search using lower case `duet` It returns `no results found` But when I search `Duet` its found.


See results when I search using `duet`

[image]

See results when I search using `Duet`

[image]

And If I use this SQL query manually in `phpmyadmin` its result found.

**So that reason I want to get data using a lower or upper case!**

Comment: If the collation on the tables ends with `_ci`, the search should be case insensitive

Comment: But If I use this SQL query manually in phpmyadmin its result found.

Comment: Please show us how you're making the query. Are you using Wordpress database connection or are you making your own?

Comment: see https://ibb.co/bgR0Jpb

Comment: Please copy/paste all relevant code into the question itself. Never post code as images.

Comment: You should also look into how to properly prepare the query. Right now, you're not really doing that since you're injecting the user data _directly_ into the query. That opens you up for SQL injection attacks. You can have a look [here](https://www.lingulo.com/quick-tips/wordpress-database-queries-how-to-do-with-prepare) about using prepare in WP properly. Note the `%s` and how they pass the data.

Comment: I added the code in questions. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: using `prepare` properly and it works. I posted an answer. thanks, @MagnusEriksson for the suggestion of using `prepare`

Comment: look here on how to prepare LIKE query for WP prepare: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using properly prepare query like:

```
 $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM tbl_brand,tbl_generic,tbl_therapeutic_area,tbl_drug 
        WHERE tbl_brand.generic_id = tbl_generic.generic_id 
        AND tbl_brand.therapeutic_area_id = tbl_therapeutic_area.therapeutic_area_id AND tbl_brand.brand_id = tbl_drug.brand_id AND LOWER(tbl_brand.brand_name) LIKE %s",'%' . $wpdb->esc_like($search) . '%',""
    ),ARRAY_A
```

And Its works.

Comment: and this is why it works: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/how-do-you-properly-prepare-a-like-sql-statement

This is the only answer that will work

Answer (score -1):

Convert your search string in lower case

```
$search=strtolower($search);
```

Then use LOWER() function to convert your field value in lower case and query like this :

```
AND LOWER(tbl_brand.brand_name) LIKE '%$search%'
```

Comment: The OP says that the query works in PHPMyAdmin. It's also slower to use something like `LOWER()` on the db-column when trying to match it since MySQL won't be able to take advantage of any index.

Comment: I already check this but not working. I don't know why it's not working on prepare query but working fine on phpmyadmin